# Hover over link colour not working html css

Tags: html, css, colors, mousehover

Im trying to change the hover colour of a rectangle shape which ive made a link.

The html is

```
<a href='page1.html'>
<div class="tri">
&nbsp;

</div>
</a>
```

and the css is

```
.tri {
width:100px;
height:200px;
background: #b51e4c;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
}
```

I think this is the code I need to put in

```
a.tri:hover { background-color: yellow;}
```

but its not working
please help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ad26Lf2j/)**

**CSS:**

```
.tri a {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background: #b51e4c;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
.tri a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tri"> <a href='page1.html'>&nbsp;</a></div>
```

Its not good practice to use `<div>` inside `<a>`. So interchanged  the position of both in html as well in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You have to add space `a[here].tri:hover { background-color: yellow;}`

```css
.tri {
width:100px;
height:200px;
background: #b51e4c;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
}
a .tri:hover { background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<a href='page1.html'>
<div class="tri">
&nbsp;

</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work correctly. Try adding the class directly to the `<a>` tag. Here is the codepen demonstrating your code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPVeoP